# JWT Authorization is failing for all endpoints

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt

So I am creating a social media application.

I used JWT token for verification on all endpoints. It's giving me custom error of "You are not authorized, Error 401"

For example: Create post is not working:

This is my code for JWT

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken")
const { createError } = require ("../utils/error.js")

const verifyToken = (req, res,next) => {
    const token = req.cookies.access_token
    if(!token) {
        return next(createError(401,"You are not authenticated!"))
    }
    jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET, (err,user) => {
        if(err) return next(createError(401,"Token is not valid!"))
        req.user = user
        next()
      }
    )
}


const verifyUser = (req, res, next) => {
    verifyToken(req,res, () => {
        if(req.user.id === req.params.id || req.user.isAdmin) {
            next()
        } else {
            return next(createError(402,"You are not authorized!"))
        }
    })
}


const verifyAdmin = (req, res, next) => {
    verifyToken(req, res, next, () => {
      if (req.user.isAdmin) {
        next();
      } else {
        return next(createError(403, "You are not authorized!"));
      }
    });
};
    

module.exports = {verifyToken, verifyUser, verifyAdmin}
```

This is my createPost API:

```
const createPost = async (req, res) => {
    const newPost = new Post(req.body);
    try {
      const savedPost = await newPost.save();
      res.status(200).json(savedPost);
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(500).json(err);
    }
  }
```

Now, in my routes files, I have attached these functions with every endpoints.

For example: In my post.js (route file)

```
//create a post
router.post("/", verifyUser, createPost);
```

When I try to access it, this is the result
[image]

But, when I remove this verify User function from my route file, it works okay.

I have tried to re-login (to generate new cookie) and then try to do this but its still giving me error.

What can be the reason?

P.S: my api/index.js file https://codepaste.xyz/posts/JNhIr9W6zNnN26CH9xWT

Comment: Have you checked that you can actually get cookie data in your request? Does your request in fact include cookie?

Comment: I don't know how can I include cookie data in request. Can you tell me how? Can you include it in the API above so I can apply it for others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging, I found out that `req.params.id` is undefined in posts routes.

It seems to work for user endpoints since it contains req.params.id

```
const verifyUser = (req, res, next) => {
    verifyToken(req,res, () => {
        if(req.user.id === req.params.id || req.user.isAdmin) {
            next()
        } else {
            return next(createError(402,"You are not authorized!"))
        }
    })
}
```

So I just replaced === with || and its working. (but its not right)

```
        if(req.user.id || req.params.id || req.user.isAdmin) {
```

Can anyone tell me the how can I truly apply validation here since in my posts routes i dont have user id in params

Comment: Include the token inside the Authorization header then access it by using this "req.header("Authorization")"